# How best to find next/last meeting across multiple Excel sheets?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-office

I'm pretty rusty on my excel and have been asked to help someone with a slightly tricky problem.

We have a number of projects going on where we are meeting the same companies for different reasons. To keep track of this and make sure people know what other conversations are happening we have a master spreadsheet (in Office 365) for the different projects and conversations - each of our internal *projects* has its own sheet in the workbook, where people list the meetings they have had and have upcoming with each company. These sheets are in a similar format, with columns of:

```
Company
Date
Attendees
Notes
```

The meetings are added by about a dozen people and not consistently so they aren't in order - but they all have consistent company and date fields.

I want to pull together a summary sheet at the start of the workbook that will show people the most recent and next upcoming meetings with each company, alongside the attendees and notes - e.g. looking through each sheet to find all the listed meetings and then 'picking' the most recent past meeting or earliest upcoming meeting.

I can't work out a simple way to do this - I've tried an INDEX MATCH approach (which I couldn't figure out how to compare where there are multiple entries for a company) and a MAXIFS / MINIFS approach (which returned zero for a lot of future meetings). Grateful for any ideas that I could put into practice here.

Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. Is each meeting on one line with a list of attendees in a single cell? Also, how many projects are we talking about? 5? 50? more? Is the number of project-sheets fixed or variable?

Comment: look up 3D functions for Excel, there will be some standard ones, but then there will also be some clever array built ones, where you can do 3D vlookup / Index and so on, there should be some ind of 3D function you could manipulate to suit your needs

Comment: @James Key,, better share some sample data, along with expected output, will help us to fix the issue!